# Gradle: MavenPublish for Apache XMLBeans generated jar

Tags: java, gradle

I have a Gradle project which generates a library of XMLBeans (Apache XMLBeans).

This will be done by calling ant.xmlbean within the gradle script.

```
task createHmiProtocol {
doLast {
    ant.taskdef(name: 'xmlbean', classname: 'org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.tool.XMLBean',
    classpath: configurations.xmlbeans.asPath)
    ant.xmlbean(
        javasource: "1.5", 
        failonerror: "true",
        fork: "yes",
        optimize : "true",
        memoryMaximumSize: "512M",
        memoryInitialSize: "64M",
        destfile: "$dist"+"/"+"$fileName"+".jar",
        classpath: configurations.xmlbeans.asPath){
            fileset(dir: src) {
                include(name: '*.xsdconfig')
                include(name: 'hmiprotocol.xsd')
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This task generates a JAR named hmiprotocol.jar and is placed in the 'dist' directory.

After building the JAR i want to publish it to our maven repository.

```
publishing {
publications {
    mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
        groupId groupIdDef
        artifactId prjName
        if (versionPropsFile.canRead()) {
            def Properties versionProps = new Properties()

            versionProps.load(new FileInputStream(versionPropsFile))
            version = versionProps['VERSION_NAME']
        }
        from components.java
    }
}
repositories {
    maven {
        credentials {
            username 'abc'
            password 'pwd'      
        }
        url releaseRepo
    }
}
}
```

When i execute this script the hmiprotocol.jar will be build and after that the publish task is executed.
But the JAR deployed in our maven repository is empty.

Executing the "publications" task whitin doLast{} doesn't work.

I think that the "from components.java" within the mavenJava block is the hitting point. 
Does anyone have a suggestions how i can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this problem.

As @Francisco Mateo mentioned, at first i create a specific task to build the XMLBeans JAR:

```
class XmlBeansTask extends DefaultTask {

@Input
private File destFile;

@Input
private String classpath;

@OutputFile
public File getDestFile() {
    return destFile;
}

@TaskAction
public void generate() {
    ant.taskdef(name: 'xmlbean', classname: 'org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.tool.XMLBean',
        classpath: classpath)
    ant.xmlbean(
        javasource: "1.5", 
        failonerror: "true",
        fork: "yes",
        memoryMaximumSize: "512M",
        memoryInitialSize: "64M",
        destfile: destFile,
        classpath: classpath){
        fileset(dir: 'src') {
            include(name: '*.xsdconfig')
            include(name: 'hmiprotocol.xsd')
        }
    }
}

public void setDestFile(String destFile){
    this.destFile = new File(destFile);    
}

public void setClasspath(String classpath){
    this.classpath = classpath;        
}
}
```

Then i defined the task parameters:

```
dependencies {
    xmlbeans 'org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:2.5.0'
    xmlbeans 'org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans-xmlpublic:2.5.0'
    xmlbeans 'org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans-xpath:2.3.0'
    xmlbeans 'org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans-qname:2.5.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:2.5.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans-xmlpublic:2.5.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans-xpath:2.3.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans-qname:2.5.0'
    implementation gradleApi()
}

task createHmiProtocol(type: XmlBeansTask){
     dependsOn 'deleteDirectories'

    destFile = 'hmiprotocol.jar'
    classpath configurations.xmlbeans.asPath
}
```

And in the publish task, i defined the artifact id:

```
publishing {
   publications {
       mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            groupId groupIdDef
            artifactId prjName
            artifact(createHmiProtocol.destFile)
       }
   }
   repositories {
       maven {
            credentials {
                username 'xyz'
                password 'password'     
            }
            url releaseRepo
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `from components.java` part is primarily for items within `src/main/java`. You are dynamically generating items with Apache XMLBeans with `doLast { }` and placing it in a location Gradle is not aware of.

This works, but isn't the best way to do it since Gradle is not able to "cache" the output which will lead to slower builds.

The best way to do the generation is to create a custom task type with the *output* being the `destfile`. For example:

```
import org.gradle.api.DefaultTask;
import org.gradle.api.file.RegularFileProperty;
import org.gradle.api.model.ObjectFactory;
import org.gradle.api.tasks.OutputFile;
import org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskAction;

import javax.inject.Inject;

public class XmlBeansTask extends DefaultTask {

    private final RegularFileProperty destFile;

    @Inject
    public XmlBeansTask(ObjectFactory objects) {
        this.destFile = objects.fileProperty();
    }

    @OutputFile
    public RegularFileProperty getDestFile() {
        return destFile;
    }

    @TaskAction
    public void generate() {
        // Do work
    }

}
```

Then simply register that task with your project and publish the task outputs with the `mavenJava` publication:

```
val createHmiProtocol = tasks.register("createHmiProtocol", XmlBeansTask::class.java)

publishing {
    publications {
        named<MavenPublication>("mavenJava") {
            artifact(createHmiProtocol)
        }
    }
}
```

The above is untested, but should hopefully guide you.

- [Developing Custom Gradle Task Types](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_tasks.html)
- [Developing Custom Gradle Plugins](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html)

Comment: Thanks @Francisco Mateo for this hint. But i don't know how to port the xmlBeans instructions in the generate() function. The other problem is, that i get an error at: val createHmiProtocol = tasks.register("createHmiProtocol", XmlBeansTask). Gradle says that "createHmiProtocol" is an unknown property.